# Excel export and save each sheet as a new file

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to automatically export and save all the sheets in my Excel file to individual files that are the name of the sheet from which they originate.

I found VBA code [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/785-excel-save-export-sheet-as-new-workbook.html) which I attempted to use but for some reason it doesn't work (I do not know if it is outdated or something else). I am completely unfamiliar with Visual Basic, but there was an error on line 34 which I managed to fix by putting a folder name in double-quotes where it says *FolderName*. However, I ran into other errors and am now looking for an updated or fixed version of this code. Or some other method entirely.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()
'Updateby20200806
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xNWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook

DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    Select Case xWb.FileFormat
        Case 51:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56:
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
End If

MkDir FolderName

For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
On Error GoTo NErro
    If xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
    xWs.Select
    xWs.Copy
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & xWs.Name & FileExtStr
    Set xNWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Application.Workbooks.Count)
    xNWb.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    xNWb.Close False, xFile
    End If
NErro:
    xWb.Activate
Next

    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code you used to your post and tell us exactly what error(s) you're getting and on which line(s).

Comment: Is the file you're running this on (`ThisWorkbook`) already saved? If not, `FolderName` won't be valid and will cause errors.

Comment: Unless you tell us what the specific problem you're having with this code is, I'm not sure how we can help.